# Recommended way to communicate setting changes for a driver in Windows IOT Core

Tags: uwp, driver, windows-10-iot-core

We are currently porting a project from Windows CE to Windows IOT Core. In Windows CE we use the registry for driver settings. Our user mode application modifies the registry and signals an event notifying the driver to update it's settings. Under Windows IOT Core (UWP) we do not have access to the registry from the UWP application. What is the recommended approach for IOT Core to achieve the same functionality?

One thought is the team would expose some ioctl codes for the application and use these to communicate changes and have the driver modify the registry, but we are unsure if this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

For me the simplest means to interact directly with drivers on windows iot core is to use w3pi.info webserver with an atlserver web application.
DISCLAIMER: I am the author of w3pi webserver.
If you take a look at the flipled sample https://w3pi.info/www/atlserver.srf you will see the level of effort is fairly small compared to other means